# Is there any logging in ReSharper to find why the test is inconclusive?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, nunit, resharper

We have very complex structure of derived classes which forms our system/integration tests. Now I started using parametrized NUnit `TestFixture` in one of my test classes and ReSharper 6.1.1 really doesn't like it.

If I run the test directly from unit test session the test fixture is always marked as inconclusive. If I run the test from code I get the same result but if I expand the Resharper's icon on the test fixture and select only single specific test case to run it will very rarely run all tests inside the fixture for that case but in most cases it will again mark the fixture as inconclusive.

My parametrized fixture works without any problem in NUnit test runner.

I also created some sample parametrized fixture with single level of inheritance and it works so the problem is somewhere inside our whole "framework" for system tests.

Is there any way to investigate why the fixture is marked as inconclusive and excluded from the test run?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a common problem with ReSharper test runner. See [this bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-287998). Try to run it with the NUnit GUI test runner to determine if the problem comes from ReSharper or your test framework.